# Append a list of item in to Angular JS array?

Tags: angularjs

So we know the code below works:

```
  $http({ method: 'POST', url: url_getMoreHouse })
        .success(function (data) {
                    alert('Works');
                    console.log(data);

                       $scope.HouseBasket = data;
                });
```

However if we want to append the data into the current basket which is:

```
         $scope.HouseBasket += data;
```

This will cause errors, I dont want to use a foreach loop to **push()** each data into the **$scope.HouseBasket** is there a faster way to add a list of Object into the angular list?

Comment: what is slow about looping and pushing...
http://devpro.it/examples/loopsbench/

Comment: In your case you just need to `concat` why even loop though..

Comment: Using a faster method instead of a loop that is what I looked for and

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> is there a faster way to add a list of Object into the angular list

How big is your data ?, Well a simple for loop will not be slower that most possible solutions, but if your destination list is big enough you could use a while loop progressively popping(or shifting) out of the array and pushing to the destination.

> $scope.HouseBasket += data; This will cause errors

You are looking for [array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) `$scope.HouseBasket = $scope.HouseBasket.concat(data);`

---

If you want to achieve this in one line you could :-

use [function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to push a list at once to the source.

```
     [].push.apply($scope.HouseBasket, data);
```

or

```
     $scope.HouseBasket = $scope.HouseBasket.concat(data);
```